# android gridview item dynamic background colour

Tags: java, android, gridview, realm

I have a GridView with realm objects, I can populate the GridView fine, what I can't work out is how to change the background colour of the item depending on a realm object variable. What I need is if the realm object stockEntry.VERIFIED is equal to 1 then the background colour needs to be green.

I did manage to get it showing green by altering the view.setBackgroundColor but then when I scroll more items automatically get a green background!

```
public class StockEntryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private List<StockEntry> stockEntries = null;

public StockEntryAdapter(Context context) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void setData(List<StockEntry> details) {
    this.stockEntries = details;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (stockEntries == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return stockEntries.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (stockEntries == null || stockEntries.get(position) == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return stockEntries.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View currentView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (currentView == null) {
        currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stock_entry_listitem, parent, false);
    }

    StockEntry stockEntry = stockEntries.get(position);

    if (stockEntry != null) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.itemnmbr);
        textView.setText(stockEntry.getItemFullName());

        if (stockEntry.getVerified() == 1) {
             // here I need to set the items background colour to green
        }
    }

    return currentView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
currentView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.R.color.yellow));
```

Comment: Also after you changed the color to what you want, you need to control the other items too you're getting more green because view is recycled so add an `else` statement to your code to default the background to the original.

Comment: He is not using view holder class so I think no need of else part.

Comment: comeback4you - that was very close to my original code, I am using currentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A5D6A7")); the problem was highlighted by @EsatIBIS - I didin't think of having an else in there for the default background, that worked, thanks to both!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both @comeback4you and @EsatIBIS, this is what worked for me;

```
public View getView(int position, View currentView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (currentView == null) {
        currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stock_entry_listitem, parent, false);
    }

    StockEntry stockEntry = stockEntries.get(position);

    if (stockEntry != null) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.itemnmbr);
        textView.setText(stockEntry.getItemFullName());
        if (stockEntry.getVERIFIED() == 1) {
            currentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A5D6A7"));
            if (stockEntry.getVARIANCECOST() > 100 || stockEntry.getVARIANCECOST() < -100) {
                currentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EF9A9A"));
            }
        } else {
            currentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    return currentView;
}
```